# Navbar not expanding to full width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

[Host Folder](https://128adea15bfc1bafb9f65665da2a849fe09dc13a.googledrive.com/host/0B71AnQstJeptYUpjOW9ZLXpTWmc)

If you click the link then click "all.html", you should see a page with an unfinished navbar. The `li`s in the list are stacking for some unknown reason. Could someone tell me why "Member Resources" and on are in a row below and how to fix that? I tried playing with the `text-align`, `float`, `width`, and `margin`s of the containing `div`, the `ul`, and the `li`s but haven't gotten anywhere. Thank you (Note: Using Bootstrap v3.3.6)!

HTML:

```
<div class="row" id="topnav">
     <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Sponsor</a>
        <li>
            <a href="#">All the rest of the li's are like the ones above, I've ommitted them to save space</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#topnav{
    display: inline;
}
#topnav *{
    display:inherit;
}
#topnav ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0,93,164);
    padding: 1.5%;
    display:inline-block;
}
#topnav li{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0 2.5%;
    }
#topnav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight:600;
}
```

SIDENOTE: Does anyone know why there is a scrollbar at the bottom of the page? There's no extra content to the right and I'm pretty sure there are no margins that'd be pushing it out that far. I see it on Chrome, anyone else see it and know why it's occuring?

Comment: bootstrap version 3.x ?

Comment: use the code given in the website and then modify it to fit your designs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should set width of `#topnav ul` to 100% for setting it to full width.**

```
#topnav ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0,93,164);
    padding: 1.5%;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Second way to see a full width navbar is to do as the bootstrap guide say**

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" id="topnav">
         <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sponsor</a>
            <li>
                <a href="#">All the rest of the li's are like the ones above, I've ommitted them to save space</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

*Look carefully to notice that the navbar is full width and of different color(left intentionally for you to notice). You can remove the background color from your ul and put it on your navbar class instead instead*

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Great :) . Don't forget to also upvote in case you liked it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML

```
<div id="topnav">
     <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Sponsor</a>
        <li>
            <a href="#">All the rest of the li's are like the ones above, I've ommitted them to save space</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#topnav{
    display: inline;
}
#topnav *{
    display:inherit;
}
#topnav ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0,93,164);
    padding: 1.5%;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
#topnav li{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0 2.5%;
    }
#topnav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight:600;
}
```

Comment: I just removed the row class on the topnav and set width 100% on the ul